# Setting Rigidbody2D body type to "static" in code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I recently updated my Unity (to 5.5.0f3 from 5.4.1f1), and now I seem to have some problems with a Rigidbody2D in one of my games.

So basically I used to use this code to make my gameobject (player) non-intractable and taken out of the physics controls:

```
Player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = true;
```

This is not working properly after the update of Unity, and upon setting the player to kinematic it keeps moving in the same direction as when it was "dynamic" (but uncontrollable). Note: this was not the case in Unity 5.4.1f1.

So I went into the Rigidbody2D component and noticed that it had changed. 
[How my old Rigidbody2D looked like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEwS9.png) and [How my new RigidBody2D looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPQMR.png)

The "kinematic" option was moved into a "body type" option, and in runtime it does change the body type to Kinematic using the ".isKinematic = true" string (but it's not working properly as mentioned before).

So I tried changing the body type value to "static" manually doing runetime and noticed that worked perfectly!

**So my question is:** How do i change the body type to static in the code? (like the "isKinematic"), and what happened in the changes to Rigidbody2D (and Kinematics?)

Comment: It seems like answers to this question will require knowledge of the Unity class library, so please consider adding the [tag:unity3d] tag.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Hi. Still kinda new to Unity/C# and the terms, so I'm not quite sure want? As far as I know I'm not using a "Unity class library". The gameobject "Player" is not tagged, but controlled in the code through the "Public Gameobject Player" (Drawn into the component box "Player" in Unity). Is this what you are requesting? or am I not making any sense. Thanks in advance

Comment: @KristofferRasmussen He means your question is Unity specific so tag it with `unity3d` (which it appears Scott did for you :) )

Comment: @LukeBriggs Ohh geez. I'm so confused. Thanks Scott ;)

Comment: @KristofferRasmussen: As soon as you use types like `Rigidbody2D` or `Player`, you are using the Unity class library (i.e. the set of classes included with Unity), because those classes are not available without Unity. Indeed, as Luke said, I was referring to tagging your question here - because most users who know C# will still have no idea about the specifics of the mentioned Unity classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [bodyType property](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-bodyType.html) on Rigidbody is probably what you're looking for:

```
Player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Static;
```

It's worth mentioning that something else *might* be wrong if updating between minor versions of Unity is what broke it, but I wouldn't know for sure without seeing more of your project.

Comment: This is working perfectly! Thanks. I'm sure something is wrong in my code, but for now this will work.

Comment: @KristofferRasmussen no problem! If you're sure it was only the update then it's either a Unity bug or you're possibly using Unity in a way that they don't expect. That's nothing to be concerned about though - this happens all the time to me too and I've been using Unity for some 8+ years :) So long as you understand what a static rigidbody is and that's actually what you want then that's fine.

Comment: Why are there 2 ways to manage body types? Is that a historical legacy?

Comment: @Seideun yes, setting `isKinematic = true;` internally does `bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Kinematic;`. Once upon a time static didn't exist and was added to allow for more performance optimisations, but an object can't be both kinematic and static thus bodyType was added instead of any sort of isStatic. This also happened long before Unity's automatic API rewrite was created, so the original isKinematic stayed and has existed ever since.